# using xampp on windows7 with varnish

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, redirect, httpconfiguration

I am using xampp on window7 with varnish.
My requirement is to redirect all requests from localhost/folder1 to localhost/folder2

I have tried to do this from varnish using probe reference but with no luck.

so I have tried with apache configuration file as below

Alias /folder1 "C:/xampp/folder2"

AllowOverride All
Order allow,deny
Allow from all

But when I request for the URL localhost/folder1 it's not going anywhere and am getting access forbidden error message. can somebody please guide me in right direction.

Comment: Why nobody answer this question?